# Regular expression in R to remove the part of a string after the last space

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I would like to have a `gsub` expression in R to remove everything in a string that occurs after the last space. E.g. `string="Da Silva UF"` should return me `"Da Silva"`. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following.

```
string <- 'Da Silva UF'
gsub(' \\S*$', '', string)

[1] "Da Silva"
```

Explanation:

```
            ' '
\S*         non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more times)
  $         before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```

Answer (score 7):

Using `$` anchor:

```
> string = "Da Silva UF"
> gsub(" [^ ]*$", "", string)
[1] "Da Silva"
```