# Remove everything after last space with stringr

Tags: r, regex, stringr, tidyverse

I have data that looks like this:

```
df <- tribble(
    ~name, ~value,
    "Jake Lake MLP", 10, 
    "Bay May CE", 5,
    "Drake Cake Jr. DSF", 9.1,
    "Sam Ram IR QQQZ", 1
)
```

I want to trim all the names so that they are:

```
"Jake Lake",
"Bay May", 
"Drake Cake Jr.",
"Sam Ram IR"
```

Basically removing everything after the last space.

I tried:

```
df %>% mutate(name = str_replace(name, "\\s.*$", ""))
```

But it's not quite what I want!

Comment: You could actually take the regex from the non-accepted answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20497895/regular-expression-in-r-to-remove-the-part-of-a-string-after-the-last-space

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can use `sub`

```
df %>% 
    mutate(name = sub("\\s+[^ ]+$", "", name))
```

Or the same pattern in `str_replace`

```
df %>% 
   mutate(name = str_replace(name, "\\s[^ ]+$", ""))
# A tibble: 4 × 2
#            name value
#           <chr> <dbl>
#1      Jake Lake  10.0
#2        Bay May   5.0
#3 Drake Cake Jr.   9.1
#4     Sam Ram IR   1.0
```

---

The pattern indicates a space (`\\s`) followed by one or more non white space (otherwise it can `\\S+`) until the end of the string and replace it with blank `""`.  In the OP's code, it was non-specific (`.*`).

Comment: could you explain whats going on with the `+[^ ]+` in the regex? I understand \\s and $.... just not the middle piece.

Comment: @emehex Whenever we use `^` inside square brackets and also have another character (here it is space), it means to match any character except the space (here)

Comment: Gotcha. I don't like the recycled `^` ... I just knew it as the opposite of `$`.

Comment: @emehex If you use it as standalone, it means the start of the string.  So its meaning differs